# how to call one applet form to another form after clicking on button

Tags: java

I have created a Button in an applet and want another applet window to be opened when I click this button.

Please explain how can I do that.

Comment: Don't use applets. They are a dying technology. Consider using Swing + JFrame instead. It is nearly identical but it isn't abandoned.

Comment: sir but college give the project on applet

Comment: sir below this is my code can you say how to do

Comment: That does not bode well for your college. Anyways, if you want help you need to include what you've tried. Eg. How are you displaying the button, then add an actionlistener to the button trigger the action. When you've provided that much. Somebody can probably tell you how to open a "Window". What are you using to view your applet, because I don't think any modern browsers still run applets.

Comment: If you edit your question to include your "answer", **and** include how you are viewing the applet, somebody might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Again, I do not recommend using applets. One of the jdk's I have installed has an applet viewer, so I whipped up this example. It has a button. You click the button, it opens another window. I run this program with:

`$appletviewer crapplet.html`.

First the `crapplet.html` file that is used to display the applet.

```
<html>
<body>
<object  width="400"  height="300">
  <param name="code" value="Crapplet.class">
  Didn't load applet.
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

Second the applet source, `Crapplet.java`.

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class Crapplet extends Applet{
    public void init(){
        JButton button = new JButton("show window");
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener( evt->{
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("what");
            Extra e = new Extra();
            e.init();
            frame.add(e);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
class Extra extends Applet{
    public void init(){
        add(new JLabel("about this"));
    }
}
```

One the button is clicked, it fire of the action event and calls the listener. Inside of the listener a JFrame is created and the next Applet class is created. The applet is init and added to the JFrame then displayed.

The only reason I did this is because it is not too far from swing. You can completely replace the Applet with a JFrame and a main method.

Comment: But sir another form is applet form and i want to call another applet form after clicking on first applet form's button

Comment: What you need to do, is edit your question to include the necessary information. As you can see I have answered your question as provided.

Comment: @SiddharthSinghRathore I have edited the answer to include a second Applet that is used instead of a JLabel.